# Use transaction in firebase cloud function to update 2 different nodes at the same time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In firebase, for each "MATCH", I need to update a COUNTER which can be positive or negative. On each COUNTER update, I would like to update a FLAG which is 1 if COUNTER >= 0 or -1 if not.
This FLAG is located on another node.

- MATCHES

  - -KtzhbMRLB36qgiIz0hT

    - COUNTER : 1211
    - FLAG : 1
  - -KtzhbMRLB36qgiIz0hU

    - COUNTER : -124
    - FLAG : -1

For the moment, to prevent against concurent writes, I use a transaction in a cloud function to update COUNTER.

```
exports.updateMatchesStrengthInIds = 

functions.database.ref('/data/ids/{idA}/MATCHES/{idB}/instances/{instanceID}/polarity').onWrite(event => {

  const instanceRef = event.data.ref.parent;
  const matchCounterRef = instanceRef.parent.parent.child('COUNTER');
  const flagRef = matchCounterRef('FLAG');
  const currentPolarity = event.data.val();

  return matchCounterRef.transaction(current => {
    var count = (current || 0) + currentPolarity;
    return count;
  }).then(() => {
     console.log('COUNTER updated, but FLAG not yet updated');
   });
});
```

This is working...

Now I'm stuck with this question : how to update at the same time FLAG to 1 or -1 depending on whether COUNTER is >=0 or <0.

It seems that transactions won't allow an update on 2 different nodes at the same time ?
In such case, is it possible to pass my counter inside the returned promise and to update the flag then ?

I'm not familiar with JS and promises...

Comment: Transactions can't be used to update two different locations.  There can only be one root location and all updates must happen underneath it.

Comment: Thanks Doug... that is what I was afraid of... Any idea on the best approach to atomically make self dependent updates on several nodes ?

Comment: You may have to restructure your data to make this possible.  If you're looking for a conversation, it might be better to post to firebase-talk with the details of what you're trying to do.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: OK thanks I will look for it